# How to add timestamp when recording with Mountebank?

Tags: virtualization, mountebank

I'd like each recorded http request & response to be timestamped (ms precision) when recording with Mountebank.

I've considerred using something like Fiddler to add the timestamp, but would rather be able to do this with Moutebank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [addDecorateBehavior](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/proxies#proxy-add-decorate-behavior) field should do the trick. You could, for example, set a header:

(request, response) => { response.headers.timestamp = new Date(); }

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this will take the timestamp at 'playback' and not at the time of 'recording'?